# Access to table via Stored Procedure when the table is in a different schema

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a stored proc: S1.ProcA -- S1 is schema -- The ProcA accesses table dbo.T1 in dbo schema.

I want user1 to be able to access dbo.T1 via S1.ProcA -- I gave exec access to S1.ProcA, but, it errors with "Select permission was denied on dbo.T1..."

How can I give access for user1 to the table dbo.T1 via the proc S1.ProcA, without directly giving access to the table?

Thanks.

Comment: SQL Serve 2008 database.  All the objects are in the same database.

Comment: A solution may be to create a view in the same schema as the procedure and then grant access to the view instead of the table

Comment: You can also try the "EXECUTE AS" clause in your Stored Procedure code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [EXECUTE AS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181362.aspx) to specify another user under whose security context the stored procedure is run.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE your_proc
WITH EXECUTE AS 'user_with_permission_on_schema'
AS SELECT * FROM your_schema.your_table
```

So if you have a login/user that has the appropriate permissions on the object referenced by the proc you can use that login/user to execute the stored proc instead of the caller.

If you want to play around with permissions in the Management Console you can use the `EXECUTE AS USER = 'user'` and `REVERT` (back to your normal login) commands to change security context while testing.

SQL Server security can be a complex topic and I suggest you read through the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510589%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) thoroughly as this is probably not an area you want to take too many chances in.

An example of how this works:

```
-- create schemas, table, users, proc and grant permissions
CREATE SCHEMA demo_s1
GO
CREATE SCHEMA demo_s2
GO
CREATE USER [schema_s1_owner] WITHOUT LOGIN WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[demo_s1]
GO
CREATE USER [schema_s2_user] WITHOUT LOGIN WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[demo_s2]
GO
CREATE TABLE demo_s1.your_table (column1 int)
INSERT demo_s1.your_table VALUES (1),(2),(3)
GO
GRANT SELECT ON demo_s1.your_table TO [schema_s1_owner]
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE select_from_s1_your_table
WITH EXECUTE AS 'schema_s1_owner'
AS SELECT * FROM demo_s1.your_table
GO
GRANT EXECUTE ON select_from_s1_your_table TO [schema_s2_user] 
GO

-- try executing as limited user
EXECUTE AS USER = 'schema_s2_user' -- change security context
SELECT * FROM demo_s1.your_table -- this will fail with 'SELECT permission was denied'
GO 
EXEC select_from_s1_your_table -- this will work and return results
GO
REVERT -- go back to the ordinary login and clean up
GO

-- clean up
DROP TABLE demo_s1.your_table 
GO
DROP PROC select_from_s1_your_table
GO
DROP USER [schema_s2_user] 
GO
DROP USER [schema_s1_owner] 
GO
DROP SCHEMA demo_s1
GO
DROP SCHEMA demo_s2
GO
```

Comment: Thanks I will implement the EXECUTE AS

Comment: @user1967701 I added a sample script to demonstrate how this can work. The script adds some stuff and then removes it.